# Powershell in batch file - last command does not execute but all execute when pasted into command prompt

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I haven't found any questions posted quite like this. As the title says, the below code executes perfectly in command prompt, but not when run as a batch file. Only the last rename-item is not executing. Both batch file and direct command being run as non-admin.

```
powershell.exe -command "& {remove-item '%APPDATA%\...\*.old' -force; remove-item '%LOCALAPPDATA%\...\2*\*.old' -force; rename-item '%APPDATA%\...\file.xml' -NewName 'file.xml.old' -force; rename-item '%LOCALAPPDATA%\...\2*\user.config' -NewName 'user.config.old' -force;}"
```

Also, I'm using this method after having some trouble with wildcards using DOS commands. I'm open to any suggestions to get the last commandlet working. Thanks in advance.

Edit: added a pause to the batch file to find that the path is considered invalid when run as batch file. Why would this differ from direct command? Assuming there is some escape character I'm missing but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after piping a get-childitem to rename-item. Still not sure why the first rename-item works, seems like an issue with wildcards in the path when run in a batch file.

Comment: Nice you got it resolved. However the answer would be better with more context. Piping a get-childitem to rename-item exactly how? Please see the [guidelines for writing a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help).